# View value is not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-bootstrap

The attribute on the view doesn't update.
When I click on the remove image, then comes a popup model.
remove image on index.html:

the attribute {{naam}} is not updating and setName has updated the name...

Comment: Can you put your `open` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using angular ui bootstrap, in your `$scope.open();` function, just add:

```
resolve: {
    naam: function () {
       return $scope.naam;
    }
}
```

And then in your modal controller, inject a `naam` and add `$scope.naam = naam`, it should do it.